# Calculate amount of digits required to represent an integer

Tags: logic

I'm trying to write an algorithm to convert a positive integer into a unique (per integer) alphanumeric string.

My character set is

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

Given that there are 62 possibilities with only one character (as there are 62 characters in my character set), how do I take an integer and calculate the amount of digits required to represent that integer in alphanumeric terms?

I'm trying to figure out how to mathematically work out the number of variations given a character set of a given size.

Can someone help me mathematically and logically break down this problem and solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 character: 62 possibilities.  2 characters: $62^2$ possibilities.  3 characters: $62^3$ possibilities.  Essentially you will be writing integers in base 62.

Comment: Won't that mean that I'll have repeating characters as `aa` and `aa` (the `a`s being in a different perceived order by the algorithm).

Comment: @NaftuliTK Not if I understand your question correctly.  Indeed $aa$ would be one of your strings, and it only gets counted once--just  as 33 just gets counted once as a base 10 numeral.

Comment: That answers my question. I was confused on whether this approach would look at different order of the digits as representing unique results.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix). It might lead you to some interesting places.

Here's my quick explanation: in our number system (base 10), we represent numbers by using symbols to mean a certain integer between (an including) 0 and 9, and position to represent what power of 10 we are multiplying the integer with in an overall sum. For example:

$256 = 2 * 10^2 + 5 * 10^1 + 6 * 10^0$.

You can see here how the position and symbols come into play. Your system would work similarly, but using 62 symbols instead of 10. You would need to assign a value to each symbol, say we start with the Arabic numbers, then lowercase letters in order, then uppercase letters in order. This means that the letter "c" would represent the number "12". Here is a similar breakdown of an arbitrary number in base 62:

$(4E)_{62} = (4 * 10^1 + E * 10^0)_{62}$

The subscript notations refer to the base that the expressions are in. Notice how I still used "10" here. In base 62, 10 would be 62. Now we can convert this further to base 10:

$(4E)_{62} = (4 * 62^1 + 40 * 62^0)_{10} = (288)_{10}$

Hopefully the idea makes a bit more sense now.